# Drupal working with external db

Tags: database, drupal, external

Hi i want to build up a site which is connected to external db.
This data store around 10000 products (ex. toys and each toy have few attributes). I am able to implement it to module how ever what would be the best direction to go ?
My thought was to build custom node module which will create node for each position but this give me plant of nodes. ( I never had chance to deal with bigger db)
What would be better solution?

Thanks for all ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choice is to use [Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate). With this module you can extend the custom module, to convert all the 10,000 Data in to nodes in Drupal system.

Trust me Migrate can handle more than 10,000 data. Actually it is not a Bigger DB.

Comment: Excellent. Didn't try yet but sound exactly the same as what i was trying to build from hand :) Thanks alot.